# Is it possible to pass object property as a reference in JS?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have an object generated from an xml document it is very deep, so I can reach a value like:

```
myobject.really[0].long.chain[43].to.travel.to.get.my[5].desired.$.value
```

If I want to update this property based on it's previous value then I could do it like this:

```
myobject.really[0].long.chain[43].to.travel.to.get.my[5].desired.$.value = 
updateFn(
  myobject.really[0].long.chain[43].to.travel.to.get.my[5].desired.$.value,
  otherparam1, otherparam2);
```

This makes my code very hard to read, is there any nice solution to pass a parameter as a reference not by value?

So then my code could look like this:

```
updateFn(ref, param1, param2) {
  // "ref =" act as a reference, "(ref)" act as a value
  ref = someThingToDoWithTheOldValue(ref);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
updateFn(
  myobject.really[0].long.chain[43].to.travel.to.get.my[5].desired.$.value,
  otherparam1, otherparam2);
// So I can omit the myobject.really[0].long.chain[43].to.travel.to.get.my[5].desired.$.value =  part
```

Comment: `var o = myobject.really[0].long.chain[43].to.travel.to.get.my[5].desired.$` then `o.value = whatever`.

Comment: if I do that, then I only have the `$` object in the 'o' variable, but I need the whole stuff later.

Comment: And you'd still have "the whole stuff" later accessible via the full chain of properties from `myobject`, in addition to having the `o` variable that is a direct reference to the `...$` object.

Comment: Related: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign a variable name to any deep down properties.

```
var desired_$ = myobject.really[0].long.chain[43].to.travel.to.get.my[5].desired.$
```

Any changes made to `desired_$` will actually reflect on `myobject.really...desired.$`

```
desired_$.value = updateFn( desired_$.value, otherparam1, otherparam2);
```

You can pass `myobject` around and `myobject.really...desired.$.value` would still be what you set through `desired_$.value` above.

---

> Does this mean if I pass the 'myobject.really[0].long.chain[43].to.travel.to.get.my[5].desired.$' as a paramter in the function, then it will reflect the canges on the original object too?

It depends on what you actually do with it. Here' the general rule: If you change a property on an object, the object stays the same - i.e. you can pass that object and its property that you changed will hold the value that you changed it to.

For example:

```
var obj = { outer: { inner: {prop: 1} } };
```

I have two function that change the properties in following ways:

```
function changeProp(prop){
    prop = 2;
}
function changeInner(inner){
    inner.prop = 2;
}
```

Then their respective effects would be as such:

```
changeProp(obj.outer.inner.prop);
obj.outer.inner.prop //=> 1   // original unchanged

changeInner(obj.outer.inner);
obj.outer.inner.prop //=> 2   // original changed!
```

So as long as you change the ***child*** property on an object, the original object reflects the changes.

Comment: Does this mean if I pass the `myobject.really[0].long.chain[43].to.travel.to.get.my[5].desired.$` as a paramter in the function, then it will reflect the canges on the original object too?

Comment: ``changeProp`` and ``changeInnerCompletely`` should work the same. The last call does not change inner.

Comment: @SamThomas Good catch! I don't even remember what I was thinking there... Edited.

Comment: @laggingreflex I was actually looking for a way to achieve it :D , something that will be interesting for beginners is that in your second function you can do as many inner.something assigns and it will get reflected back to the original object. But as soon as you assign inner itself to something else, the underlying lvalue for inner changes and you have lost the reference. Any following inner.something assignments won't reflect back.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like

```
    function setProp(ref, prop, val)
    {
           ref[prop] = val;
    }

    ...
      setProp(myobject.really[0].long.chain[43].to.travel.to.get.my[5].desired.$, "value", "new Value");
```

but I doubt that this makes your code more readable anyhow ...

**IDEA**

add a generic setter to each object:

```
    Object.prototype.setProp = function(prop, val)
    {
           this[prop] = val;
    }
```

and then:

```
myobject.really[0].long.chain[43].to.travel.to.get.my[5].desired.$.setProp("value", "new Value");
```

small [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/d4y5o8oq/)